# Executing .ps1 function from Task Scheduler not resulting correct result

Tags: powershell

When I run below PowerShell function to stop the service from PowerShell window it is working fine.
But When I schedule the same function and run it from task scheduler it did not stop the service and there is no event captured in the event viewer as well.

```
#Function to stop the service
function StopService {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="ServiceName")]
        [string]$ServiceName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="ComputerName")]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
        Param($Service)
        Stop-Service $Service
    } -ArgumentList $ServiceName
}
```

Task Scheduler Details:

[image]

Comment: Your script only defines the function, it doesn't actually execute it. Put `StopService $args[0] $args[1]` on the last line of the script to execute

Comment: As @MathiasR.Jessen points out - your script file defines a function called `StopService`, but it never actually runs the function.

Answer (score 0):

After removing (or) Commenting function FunctionName from the .ps1 file it is working fine. Now I able to run it from task scheduler without any issues.

```
#Function to stop the service
#Function StopService 
#   {
   [cmdletbinding()]
    Param
    (
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="ServiceName")]
    [string]$ServiceName,
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="ComputerName")]
    [string]$ComputerName
    )

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {param($Service) Stop-Service $Service} -ArgumentList $ServiceName

#    }
```